# Does Heidegger ever develop his distinction between modern and traditional technology in detail?

Tags: heidegger, philosophy-of-technology

Mark Blitz's article [Understanding Heidegger on Technology](https://www.thenewatlantis.com/publications/understanding-heidegger-on-technology) (*The New Atlantis, 2014*) describes Heidegger's distinction between modern and traditional technology in the following way:

> Everything encountered technologically is exploited for some
>   technical use. It is important to note, as suggested earlier, that
>   when Heidegger speaks of technology’s essence in terms of challenging
>   or positionality, he speaks of modern technology, and excludes
>   traditional arts and tools that we might in some sense consider
>   technological. For instance, the people who cross the Rhine by walking
>   over a simple bridge might also seem to be using the bridge to
>   challenge the river, making it a piece in an endless chain of use. But
>   Heidegger argues that the bridge in fact allows the river to be
>   itself, to stand within its own flow and form. By contrast, a
>   hydroelectric plant and its dams and structures transform the river
>   into just one more element in an energy-producing sequence. Similarly,
>   the traditional activities of peasants do not “challenge the
>   farmland.” Rather, they protect the crops, leaving them “to the
>   discretion of the growing forces,” whereas “agriculture is now a
>   mechanized food industry.”
>
> Modern machines are therefore not merely more developed, or
>   self-propelled, versions of old tools such as water or spinning
>   wheels. Technology’s essence “has already from the outset abolished
>   all those places where the spinning wheel and water mill previously
>   stood.”

I find Heidegger's argument here rather poor and underdeveloped. The distinction can be understood in at least two ways:

1. Modern technology is different from traditional tools because our modern *attitude* towards the world is instrumental, i.e. the difference is our perspective. With a different philosophical attitude - one where nature and people are not mere "raw materials for technical operations" - the same modern technology could be afforded the same status as the traditional one.
2. Modern technology is *in itself* different from traditional tools, perhaps because a modern instrumental attitude is needed to develop it in the first place. Perhaps there is even an aesthetic component involved: consider the perceived difference between a medieval stone bridge and a modern industrial metal-and-concrete bridge. It could be hypothesized that Heidegger would describe the latter as so foreign that it can only be experienced instrumentally, i.e. technologically.

Does Heidegger mean any of those two things (or both)? Does he ever develop his distinction more thoroughly than summarized above?

Comment: I just tried skimming the article (perhaps insufficiently), because I don't recall  modern vs traditional technology being a major axis in either *Being and Time* or "The Question Concerning Technology". Can you add references to where the author thinks this comes from in Heidegger's text?

Comment: With respect to your point one, that won't work because part of the point is that technology for Heidegger is not mere devices but precisely the way in which technology reshapes our relationship to "world" and takes us away from "earth"

Comment: @virmaior the example with the bridge and hydroelectric plant is given in [The Question Concerning Technology](http://www.psyp.org/question_concerning_technology.pdf) (page 7). I cannot find the exact quotes in it, but it appears that there are two versions of the text, as pointed out by [this article](http://notphilosophy.com/framing-heidegger-technology-and-the-notebooks/). I'd imagine the rest is from some of his other lectures, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @virmaior regarding your comment on point one: the issue is precisely that the relationship is neither fixed nor universal: Heidegger's own philosophical stance demonstrates that. Did you mean that H. doesn't think it's possible to alter the relationship because the technology imposes it in inescapable way?

Comment: in a sense technology imposes nothing, but the existence and use of technology change the rel. b/w DS and its world.

Comment: Page 7 doesn't instantly say what you're suggesting -- that there's some sort of earlier / later technology distinction that Heidegger develops. My main point is that what you really need to do is ask the author of that article (not Heidegger) because this modern vs traditional tech thing is from that author afaik.

Comment: The distinction to me seems clearly implied even in the examples given, as does apparently to Blitz who points it out. But as you say, it could be that this is something much more understated in Heidegger's work and that he never frames it as such. Be that as it may, from what you're saying it appears that the answer to my original question is _no_ - Heidegger never develops this further. I'll see if I can find any other references (asking Heidegger is obviously out of the question :)).

Comment: It's nowhere near  clearly implied or if it is, it has not at all been a significant part of interpreting the literature. If you think it's implied, write an article about it. (I'm hesitant to make my impression an answer as Heidegger is more of an AOC than AOS for me so I can't definitely speak to every text ... but there's no text I know of where Heidegger develops this).

Comment: I like Heideggers take on technology. You might like to check out the speech he gave at the funeral of his friend the pianist Conradin Kruetzer.in 1955.

Comment: @virmaior to be clear, I read Blitz's article on Heidegger first before any original work, so I might be biased because of Blitz's interpretation. I took it for granted that the dichotomy is established, but apparently it's not.